# Spring Integration no output-channel or replyChannel

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am working on a scenario where I have to get token in 1st call and then validate that token in the 2nd call.

My spring integration files looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws"
       xmlns:http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

    <!-- Entry channel into this flow is ucipTopupChannel -->

    <integration:transformer id="ayobaSmsRequestTransformer"
                             input-channel="ayobaSMSChannel"
                             output-channel="ayobaSmsTransformerOutputChannel"
                             ref="ayobaSmsTransformer"
                             method="ayobaSmsRequestTransform" />

    <integration:channel id="ayobaSmsTransformerOutputChannel" />

    <integration:header-value-router id="ayobaSmsValidationRouter" input-channel="ayobaSmsTransformerOutputChannel" header-name="VALIDATION">
        <integration:mapping value="FAILED" channel="ayobaSmsValidationFailedChannel"  />
        <integration:mapping value="PASSED" channel="ayobaSmsValidationRouterOutputChannel" />
    </integration:header-value-router>

    <integration:channel id="ayobaSmsValidationFailedChannel" />

    <integration:service-activator input-channel="ayobaSmsValidationFailedChannel" ref="validationFailedServiceActivator" />

    <integration:channel id="ayobaSmsValidationRouterOutputChannel" />

    <integration:object-to-json-transformer id="ayobaJsonTransformer"
                                            input-channel="ayobaSmsValidationRouterOutputChannel"
                                            output-channel="ayobaJsonChannel"
                                            object-mapper="customObjectMapper"
                                            content-type="application/json" />

    <integration:channel id="ayobaJsonChannel" />

    <http:outbound-gateway id="ayobaSmsOutboundGateway"
                           extract-request-payload="true"
                           url-expression="headers['url']"
                           request-channel="ayobaJsonChannel"
                           reply-channel="ayobaSmsOutputChannel"
                           mapped-request-headers="contentType,ERSREFERENCE,Authorization"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                           rest-template="ayobaRestTemplate" />

    <integration:transformer id="ayobaSmsResponseTransformer"
                             input-channel="ayobaSmsOutputChannel"
                             ref="ayobaSmsTransformer"
                             method="ayobaSmsResponseTransform" />

    <integration:channel id="ayobaSmsOutputChannel" />


</beans>
```

But now I have to check tokenExpiry for which I am trying to save my extra call, but I am getting below error

> Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available

and my config file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws"
       xmlns:http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

    <!-- Entry channel into this flow is ucipTopupChannel -->

    <integration:transformer id="ayobaSmsRequestTransformer"
                             input-channel="ayobaSMSChannel"
                             output-channel="ayobaSmsTransformerOutputChannel"
                             ref="ayobaSmsTransformer"
                             method="ayobaSmsRequestTransform" />

    <integration:channel id="ayobaSmsTransformerOutputChannel" />

    <integration:header-value-router id="ayobaSmsValidationRouter" input-channel="ayobaSmsTransformerOutputChannel" header-name="VALIDATION">
        <integration:mapping value="FAILED" channel="ayobaSmsValidationFailedChannel"  />
        <integration:mapping value="PASSED" channel="ayobaSmsValidationRouterOutputChannel" />
        <integration:mapping value="CACHED" channel="ayobaSmsOutputChannel" />
    </integration:header-value-router>

    <integration:channel id="ayobaSmsValidationFailedChannel" />

    <integration:service-activator input-channel="ayobaSmsValidationFailedChannel" ref="validationFailedServiceActivator" output-channel="ayobaSmsOutputChannel" requires-reply="false" />

    <integration:channel id="ayobaSmsValidationRouterOutputChannel" />

    <integration:object-to-json-transformer id="ayobaJsonTransformer"
                                            input-channel="ayobaSmsValidationRouterOutputChannel"
                                            output-channel="ayobaJsonChannel"
                                            object-mapper="customObjectMapper"
                                            content-type="application/json" />


    <integration:channel id="ayobaJsonChannel1" />

    <http:outbound-gateway id="ayobaSmsOutboundGateway"
                           extract-request-payload="true"
                           url-expression="headers['url']"
                           request-channel="ayobaJsonChannel"
                           reply-channel="ayobaSmsOutputChannel"
                           mapped-request-headers="contentType,ERSREFERENCE,Authorization"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                           rest-template="ayobaRestTemplate" />

    <integration:channel id="ayobaJsonChannel" />

    <http:outbound-gateway id="ayobaSmsOutboundGateway"
                           extract-request-payload="true"
                           url-expression="headers['url']"
                           request-channel="ayobaJsonChannel"
                           reply-channel="ayobaSmsOutputChannel"
                           mapped-request-headers="contentType,ERSREFERENCE,Authorization"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                           rest-template="ayobaRestTemplate" />

    <integration:transformer id="ayobaSmsResponseTransformer"
                             input-channel="ayobaSmsOutputChannel"
                             ref="ayobaSmsTransformer"
                             method="ayobaSmsResponseTransform" />

    <integration:channel id="ayobaSmsOutputChannel" />


</beans>
```

Now, I am startled because for the last channel `ayobaSmsResponseTransformer`, it works fine for the validation call and doesn't give error, but for my Cached Token call, it is throwing exception.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
<integration:transformer id="ayobaSmsResponseTransformer"
                         input-channel="ayobaSmsOutputChannel"
                         ref="ayobaSmsTransformer"
                         method="ayobaSmsResponseTransform" />
```

Does not have an `output-channel` definition therefore it tries to resolve a `replyChannel` header which is not present in the message when you route from the `ayobaSmsValidationRouter`.

You showed only a `ayobaSmsRequestTransformer`, but it is not clear what sends messages to its `ayobaSMSChannel`.

Perhaps you have a `<gateway>` upfront with respective messaging contracts on its methods. And perhaps you have a `void` for that `CACHED` token. And from here it looks like you don't use the latest Spring Integration.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway

> Starting with version 5.4, when gateway method return type is void, the framework populates a replyChannel header as a nullChannel bean reference if such a header is not provided explicitly. This allows any possible reply from the downstream flow to be discarded, meeting the one-way gateway contract.

And see the latest version to upgrade: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn